# Why (dictionary.keys()).sort() is not working in python?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm new to Python and can't understand why a thing like this does not work.
I can't find the issue raised elsewhere either.

```
toto = {'a':1, 'c':2 , 'b':3}
toto.keys().sort()           #does not work (yields none)
(toto.keys()).sort()         #does not work (yields none)
eval('toto.keys()').sort()   #does not work (yields none)
```

Yet if I inspect the type I see that I invoke sort() on a list, so what is the problem..

```
toto.keys().__class__     # yields <type 'list'>
```

The only way I have this to work is by adding some temporary variable, which is ugly

```
temp = toto.keys()
temp.sort()
```

What am I missing here, there must be a nicer way to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure about the solution but aren't dictionary keys unordered?

Comment: @Shraptnel: you are correct. The OP is placing the keys into a list and sorting that list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sort()` sorts the list *in place*. It returns `None` to prevent you from thinking that it's leaving the original list alone and returning a sorted copy of it.

Answer (score 6):

```
sorted(toto.keys())
```

Should do what you want.  The sort method you're using sorts in place and returns None.

Comment: Alternatively, use `sorted(toto.iterkeys())` in case the dict is large to prevent the creation and destruction of the unsorted keys list.

Comment: In Python 2.6 and 3.x you can just use `sorted(toto)` to get the same result. In fact, the use of `.keys()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

`sort()` method sort in place, returning `none`. You have to use `sorted(toto.keys())` which returns a new iterable, sorted.

Comment: Is there any way to retain a similar postfix notation ?

Like for len, one can use
    alist.__len__() 

instead of
    len(alist)

Comment: if you are calling l.__len__() it means that you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. 
I have a hard time not using postfix notation though like 
alist.map().filter().sort().map().len()

it puts the operation close to its arguments, so its really handy, instead of 

operation1(operation2(operation3(arg, arg3), arg2),arg1)

Comment: what you want to do is called method chaining. it's a pattern which is not implemented by any standard python type.